# jQuery just not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason my jQuery script just doesn't want to work, and it's really really simple, I've taken everything away except the actual jquery script, it's really annoying please help.
Thank you!

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#click").click(function () {
                alert("works!");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" id="click">Button</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

P.S. jQuery JS file is valid.

Comment: is the jquery path valid ? is javascript enabled on your browser ? try to open the js console in your browser to see if there is an error

Comment: The solution is covered in pretty much all introductory jQuery tutorials, including [this one](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works) (for which there is a link on the jquery.com homepage).

Comment: Ah man, I've been away from jQuery for so long I'm forgetting, I forgot about doc ready, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7):

Change your code to this. It ensures that the JavaScript is executed once all your HTML elements have been loaded to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#click").click(function() {
      alert("works!");
   });
});
```

However, **you should move your script tags to the bottom of the page**, to ensure that they do not block. This will also mean you don't actually need the $(document).ready callback.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your code within

```
$(function(){
    // your code here which relies on DOM elements
});
```

Otherwise you DOM has not been loaded and events will not be bound to elements.

Comment: I didn't down vote but the likely reason is because you said "Otherwise your DOM has not been loaded.". That statement is incorrect - the DOM always loads in a properly coded page, it is just that the jQuery code needs to wait for the DOM to be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your functions into the `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function() {
        alert("works!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your code inside `document.ready` like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#click").click(function () {
       alert("works!");
   });
});
```

or add your code at the end of the document like this

```
<body>
   <a href="#" id="click">Button</a>
   // Other elements...
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#click").click(function () {
                alert("works!");
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
//TO DO  your code goes here         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your script tag to the "/body" tag.
That will let the browser create the DOM and read script's one by one!
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#click").live("click",function() {
    alert("works!");
});
```

Comment: This is over-engineering the solution, at the cost of performance. This code will be executed at every point an item is added to the DOM which is inefficient.

Comment: `live()` has been removed from jQuery v1.9 so I would avoid using this anymore.